# How to only show module in joomla

Tags: joomla

I have a problem linking from a menu item to a module that I want to show. The problem is that the module does not have a custom item showing in the Menu item selection.

This means I end up having to link to an article. But that will show a lot of unwanted information like headers and other stuff from the single article.

How can I avoid that?

```
The options
1. link directly to the facebook module I wan to show with no article
2. Hide all information from the "single article"
```

Comment: Make a menu link to featured and tell it to display no articles. Or make an article override for a specific single article that doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want disable all information form article you can go to your article you want modify and go to `Options` tab.

Here you can hide all information

You can add directly module on your article with:

```
{loadposition myposition}
```

`myposition` is the position module that you have selected in module creation.

You can add a position who not use by other module.

Comment: I found that the information that I was trying to hide like the article header is from the menu item and not the article in itself.